# Pass another control as property value in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

Consider a XAML snippet like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="myButton"/>
    <m:MyControl Button="myButton"/>
</Grid>
```

Of course this doesn't work. But what I need is to pass the Button control instance named "myButton" as value to the other control's `Button` property. I've also tried it with `{StaticResource myButton}` but it fails telling me that the resource cannot be found.

What's the correct XAML syntax for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `MyControl.Button` is a DependencyProperty you can do it so

```
<m:MyControl Button="{Binding ElementName=myButton}" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not a dependency property. I've tried your suggestion but this leads to an error that bindings are only possible for DPs. And since that entire class isn't even a dependency object, I think dependency properties are not an option.

Comment: Okay, I managed to make my other class derive from DependencyObject and now I can use that binding. Thank you.

Comment: Yep dependency prop is the way to go. Nice job figuring it out.